# How to say "Dealing with someone about something"

Tags: usage

I wish to say:

> He **deals with** clients **about** the overdue invoices.

I tried to express it in next way:

> あの人は顧客**の**支払期限が過ぎた請求書**に対応する**。

But I don't like it. I feel like I use the wrong verb and the wrong grammar to express the idea I need. Could you please help me with any idea?

Answer (score 3):

> He deals with clients about the overdue invoices.

Your answer: あの人は顧客**の**支払期限が過ぎた請求書**に対応する**。
My answer 1: 彼は　　顧客**の**支払期限が過ぎた請求書**を処理する**。
My answer 2: 彼は　　支払期限が過ぎた顧客**の**請求書**を処理する**。

My answer 2 sounds more natural to me than my answer 1.

Though the position of 顧客 in your answer and my answer 1 may be grammatically correct, my answer 2 sounds more natural to me than the other.

Why?
I don't know the true answer of the position of 顧客.

I think "overdue" is more important than "the client" in this phrase, so the more important word is put in the more front position than the other; and the positioning of them make this phrase sound more natural.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!
Especially second example I liked a lot!